# Linear Differential Equation Initial Value Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Below I have the question and my steps to my current answer. Would this be correct? Thank you

> $$\frac{dy}{dt}+y=11, y(0)=5$$ $$y'+y=11$$ $$p(t)=1 \rightarrow
>  e^{\int p(t)dt}=e^t$$ $$e^t(y'+y)=11(e^t)$$ $$\int e^t(y'+y) dt= \int
>  11(e^t)dt$$ $$e^ty=11e^t+C$$ $$y=\frac{11e^t+C}{e^t}$$
>    $$5=\frac{11e^0+C}{e^0}$$ $$C = -6$$ $$y=\frac{11e^t-6}{e^t}$$

Comment: It is indeed correct.

Comment: yes that's true.

Comment: I think others would likely write it as $11-6e^{-t}$, but the answer looks good.